# OpenGL add blend mode on frame buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, openframeworks, blending

The rendering is different if I render my scene directly on the screen, and if I render on a FBO (frame buffer object), I suspect that the add blend mode is not working in the later case:

Here is the result directly on screen:

[image: Rendering directly on screen]

Here is the result with a frame buffer:

[image]

As you can see, in the frame buffer the blue color does not sum to become bright.

To draw on screen I just call the draw particles function:

```
 drawParticles();
```

And for the FBO (with ofFbo from openframeworks):

```
 ofClear(0, 0, 0, 0);

 fbo.begin();
 drawParticles();
 fbo.end();

 fbo.draw(0,0);
```

---- EDIT ----

This is how the fbo is initialized:

```
fbo.allocate(ofGetScreenWidth(), ofGetScreenHeight(), GL_RGBA32F_ARB);
```

Here is my whole code, to draw on screen I use this version, and to draw on the fbo I uncomment the comments:

```
//            ofClear(0, 0, 0, 0);
//            bodyFBO.begin();

            if(persistence>0)
            {
                ofSetColor(0,0,0,255*(1.0-persistence));
                ofFill();
                ofRect(0, 0, ofGetScreenWidth(), ofGetScreenHeight());
            }
            else
                ofBackground(0, 0, 0);

            effects[effect]->draw();
//            bodyFBO.end();

            ofEnableAlphaBlending();
//            bodyFBO.draw(0,0);
```

And here is the actual drawing, in effects[effect]->draw():

```
ofSetColor(color);

ofEnableBlendMode(OF_BLENDMODE_ADD);

ofEnablePointSprites();

ofTexture &texture = textureIndex>0?texture2:texture1;
texture.bind();

vbo.draw(GL_POINTS, 0, (int)points.size());

texture.unbind();

ofDisablePointSprites();
```

---- EDIT 2 ----

Another piece of code showing the same problem (by mikewesthad from openframeworks forum):

```
void testApp::setup(){
    ofSetFrameRate(60);
    ofSetBackgroundAuto(false);
    ofBackground(0);

    fbo.allocate(ofGetWidth()/2, ofGetHeight(), GL_RGBA32F);
    fbo.begin();
        ofBackground(0);
    fbo.end();
}

void testApp::draw(){
    // Draw directly to screen
    drawCircle();

    // Draw to fbo
    fbo.begin();
        drawCircle();
    fbo.end();
    ofDisableBlendMode();
    fbo.draw(ofGetWidth()/2, 0);
}

void testApp::drawCircle() {
    ofEnableAlphaBlending();
    ofSetColor(0, 0, 0, 2);
    ofFill();
    ofRect(0, 0, ofGetScreenWidth(), ofGetScreenHeight());
    ofSetColor(50, 50, 255, 255);
    ofEnableBlendMode(OF_BLENDMODE_ADD);
    ofCircle(ofRandomWidth()/2, ofRandomHeight(), 50);
```

[image: add blending problem on fbo]

---- Answer ----

There was missing `ofSetColor(255,255,255);` before drawing the FBO.

To have the exact same thing on the screen and on the FBO, I also needed to allocate my FBO using GL_RGB (with the default parameters in openframeworks):

```
fbo.allocate(ofGetWidth()/2, ofGetHeight(), GL_RGB);
```

Comment: What is the FBO configuration?

Comment: What do you mean? I added how I initialized the FBO in the edit...

Comment: How the FBO was created, but you are using an abstraction, also what GPU are you using?

Comment: Here is how it is created with openframeworks: https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/openFrameworks/gl/ofFbo.cpp#L219

Comment: And here is the allocate function: https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/openFrameworks/gl/ofFbo.cpp#L411

Comment: I use an NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT with 512 MB